# Rocketchat connection to secure MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, authentication, rocket.chat

I'm trying to secure mongodb added a rocketchat user with privileges and here is the query result:

```
rs01:PRIMARY> use admin
rs01:PRIMARY> show users
{
        "_id" : "admin.rocketchatuser",
        "user" : "rocketchatuser",
        "db" : "admin",
        "customData" : {

        },
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "admin"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "local"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "dbOwner",
                        "db" : "rocketchat"
                }
        ]
}
```

And here is my connection string:

```
MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://rocketchatuser:mypassword@localhost:27017/local?authSource=admin&replSet=rs01
MONGO_URL=mongodb://rocketchatuser:mypassword@localhost:27017/rocketchat?authSource=admin
```

And here is mongodb log:

```
Unauthorized: not authorized on rocketchat to execute command
```

But still getting connection refused error.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I figured out the problem after re-follow instructions in [this guide](https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/docker-containers/high-availability-install/#guide-to-install-rocketchat-as-ha-with-mongodb-replicaset-as-backend) and  enabling logging from Rocket.Chat service and see that it requires to grant rocketuser to have a role clusterMonitor on admin database:

```
db.runCommand({ grantRolesToUser: "rocketchatuser" , roles: [{role: "clusterMonitor", db: "admin"}]})
```

After granting the user it connected and started to run successfully.